# Hard problem :Prove that $f(x)<\frac{3}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: limits, derivatives, inequality, power-series, gamma-function

Define the function $1<x<\frac{103}{100}$:

$$f(x)=x^{2 \Bigg(1-0.5 \Bigg(\frac{\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)}{\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)}\Bigg)\Bigg)}+(1-x)^{2 \Bigg(1-0.5 \Bigg(\frac{\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{1-x}\Big)}{\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)}\Bigg)\Bigg)}$$

Prove that :

$$f(x)<\frac{3}{2}x-\frac{1}{2}$$

I strongly believe that it is a problem of tangent .

So the natural way is to use derivative but first there is a limit that I cannot evaluate

$$\lim_{x\to 1^{+}}(1-x)^{2 \Bigg(1-0.5 \Bigg(\frac{\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{1-x}\Big)}{\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)}\Bigg)\Bigg)}=0$$

I have tried power series at the first order of the Gamma function ($x=1$) we have :

$$\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{1-x}\Big)=1-\gamma\Big(\frac{1}{1-x}-1\Big)+O\Big(\Big(\frac{1}{1-x}-1\Big)^2\Big)$$

But it's ineffective unfortunately .

Why this limit ?

Because it implies that if:

$$g(x)=(1-x)^{2 \Bigg(1-0.5 \Bigg(\frac{\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{1-x}\Big)}{\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)}\Bigg)\Bigg)}$$

Then :

$$\lim_{x\to 1^{+}}g'(x)=0$$

Then we have just to evaluate the [derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20derivative%20%28x%29%5E%282%281-0.5Gamma%281%2F%28x%29%29%2FGamma%280.5%29%29%29%20) of :

$$h(x)=x^{2 \Bigg(1-0.5 \Bigg(\frac{\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)}{\Gamma\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)}\Bigg)\Bigg)}$$

As $x\to 1^{+}$

An conclude with the formula :

$$y=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)$$

My question :

How to prove the strict inequality ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Old boy, how do you find all this brilliant stuff? I'd like something to do with $698573$ next.

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон Well some month ago I litteraly fall in love with an inequality of Vasile Cirtoaje . See this paper https://www.isr-publications.com/jnsa/articles-1563-proofs-of-three-open-inequalities-with-power-exponential-functions (Proposition 5.2).For the rest it's simple consideration on special function and elementary function .If you want my name it's : Max Louvrier .Good day !

Comment: Monsieur Louvrier, I wish you the best. I can tell you confidently that your questions are brilliant, and you seem to pull rabbits out of the hat as far as I am concerned!